# Azure convert genericResourceInner

Tags: c#, azure, azure-management-api

I'm trying to read all azure assets in all of our subscriptions by doing the following:
1. Connect to subscription
2. Load ResourceManagmentClient and run over all resources
The type of each element is GenericResourceInner.
I try to convert each of those elements into it's relevant object but all of my efforts went down the drain since the object Type is, for example, **Microsoft.Cache/Redis**.
Is there an easier way to convert/find the relevant C# object besides doing a big switch/case?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easier way to convert/find the relevant C# object besides doing a big switch/case?

If you want to find the resource by type without use switch/case you could using the following code.

```
 var result = resourceManagement.Resources.ListWithHttpMessagesAsync().Result;
 var typeList = result.Body.ToArray().GroupBy(x=>x.Type);
 var redis = typeList.Where(x => x.Key.Equals("Microsoft.Cache/Redis"));
```